# Scala: how to determine if a type is nullable

Tags: scala, nullable

I have two questions about nullable types in Scala:

1. Let's say I wish to define a new class: `class myClass[T](x: T)`, and I'd like to make sure that `T` is nullable. How do I do that?
2. I'd like to write a function `def myFunc(x: T)` (not as part of the previous question), and I'd like to perform one thing if `T` is nullable or another if not. The difference from the previous question is that here I don't wish to limit `T`, but rather know if it's nullable or not. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Use a `>: Null <: AnyRef` bound:

```
@ def f[T >: Null <: AnyRef](arg: T): T = arg
defined function f

@ f(10)
cmd3.sc:1: inferred type arguments [Any] do not conform to method f's type parameter bounds [T >: Null <: AnyRef]
val res3 = f(10)
           ^
cmd3.sc:1: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(10)
 required: T
val res3 = f(10)
             ^
Compilation Failed

@ f("a")
res3: String = "a"
```

2. Use implicit type constraints with default values:

```
@ def isNullable[T](arg: T)(implicit sn: Null <:< T = null, sar: T <:< AnyRef = null): Boolean = sn != null && sar != null
defined function isNullable

@ isNullable(10)
res8: Boolean = false

@ isNullable("a")
res9: Boolean = true
```

These are similar to static type bounds, except that they are performed during implicit resolution instead of type checking and therefore permit failures if you provide default values for them (`null`s in this case, no pun intended :))

Comment: `isNullable[Any](3)` returns `true`, is this intended?

Comment: Nope, I think I used an incorrect operator there, it should be `&&` not `||`. Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

In scala, all types that extend `AnyRef` (equivalent of `Object`) are nullable. Most of the scala community avoids using nulls though, and tends to be more explicit by representing the existence/absence of a value with `Option`.

Answer (score 4):

"Nullable" means that it is a subclass of `AnyRef` (and not `Nothing`), therefore, you can enforce that `MyClass` takes only nullable instances as follows:

```
case class MyClass[T <: AnyRef](t: T)

MyClass("hey")
MyClass[String](null)
MyClass(null)
// MyClass[Int](3) won't compile, because `Int` is primitive
```

---

To determine whether a type is nullable, you could provide implicit methods that generate nullability tokens:

```
sealed trait Nullability[-T]
case object Nullable extends Nullability[AnyRef] {
  def isNull(t: Any): Boolean = t == null
}
case object NotNullable extends Nullability[AnyVal]
object Nullability {
  implicit def anyRefIsNullable[T <: AnyRef]: Nullability[T] = Nullable
  implicit def anyValIsNotNullable[T <: AnyVal]: Nullability[T] = NotNullable
}

def myFunc[T](t: T)(implicit nullability: Nullability[T]): Unit = {
  nullability match {
    case Nullable => 
      if (t == null) {
        println("that's a null")
      } else {
        println("that's a non-null object: " + t)
      }
    case NotNullable => println("That's an AnyVal: " + t)
  }
}
```

Now you can use `myFunc` as follows:

```
myFunc("hello")
myFunc(null)
myFunc(42)

// outputs:
// that's a non-null object: hello
// that's a null
// That's an AnyVal: 42
```

This won't compile if you try to use `myFunc` on `Any`, because the compiler won't be able to determine whether it's `AnyRef` or `AnyVal`, and the two implicit methods will clash. In this way, it can be ensured at compile time that we don't accidentally use `myFunc` on `Any`, for which the nullability cannot be determined at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

Even though we don't use `null` in `Scala` that often (in favor of `Option`) you may force function to take nullable parameter with

```
def f[T <: AnyRef](x: T) = ???
```

Comment: Note that this is not enough in general - `T` must also be a supertype of `Null` to be nullable (since `Nothing` is not nullable). Although in the case when you have values of the passed type, it probably does not matter.

Comment: @VladimirMatveev Good catch! It actually could matter if the signature were something like `def f[T <: AnyRef](x: => T) = ???`, because if one could differentiate between something and `Nothing`, one could skip the evaluation of `x` in the `Nothing`-case, without throwing any runtime exceptions.